# Json not derserialising correctly

Tags: json, vb.net, class

Json string is not deserialsing correctly

have played around with my classes etc, but bfevent always returns Nothing
have tried Public Property bfevent As BFEvent() in case it needs to be able to take multi values

pretty sure it's something simple....

```
strcatalogue = "{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": [{ "event": { "id": "29202748", "name": "Kings XI Punjab v Mumbai Indians", "countryCode": "GB", "timezone": "GMT", "openDate": "2019-03-30T10:30:00.000Z" }, "marketCount": 20 }, { "event": { "id": "29201119", "name": "Victoria v NSW Blues", "countryCode": "AU", "timezone": "GMT", "openDate": "2019-03-27T23:30:00.000Z" }, "marketCount": 2 }, { "event": { "id": "29202753", "name": "Chennai Super Kings v Rajasthan Royals", "countryCode": "GB", "timezone": "GMT", "openDate": "2019-03-31T14:30:00.000Z" }, "marketCount": 35 }], "id": 1 }"
Dim objJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BFEventList)(strCatalogue)


Public Class BFEvent
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property countryCode As String
    Public Property timezone As String
    Public Property openDate As DateTime
End Class

Public Class BFResult
    Public Property bfevent As BFEvent
    Public Property marketCount As Integer
End Class

Public Class BFEventList
    Public Property jsonrpc As String
    Public Property result As BFResult()
    Public Property id As Integer
End Class
```

BFEvent = Nothing

marketCount works fine, so something to do with BFEvents class

[image]

Comment: seems like the classes are good, what is the error u get?

Comment: no error - just fails to return anything for bfevent. bfevent=nothing marketcount=1

Comment: have added image

Comment: you are trying to read a value that refers to a class

Comment: trouble is the class = Nothing when it should have 5 values

Answer (score 0):

So i renamed my class to refer to the actual string values in the json. So bfevent is now event. I'm not sure if this is 'required' or not. Will test that elsewhere where i have working code.

But am now getting 'Keyword is not a valid identifier' for

```
Public Property Event As BFEvent()
```

with Event underlined.

No errors here

```
Dim Name As String = objJson.result(0).Event(0).name
```

But cannot compile due to above error

Comment: In `BFEventList`, change `result` in `List(Of BFResult)`. In `BFResult`, add an attribute: `<JsonProperty("event")> Public Property EventData As BFEvent`. Now you can deserialize correctly and serialize the root class to the original JSON. A `<JsonProperty(...)>` allows to specify the original property name, useful when the name is not, for example, compatible with a language reserved names. You could also enclose the reserved name in square brakets (`[Event]`). Better don't.

Comment: thanks Jimi but not sure i quite follow what to put where

Comment: Read the comment again. => Do you have a `BFEventList` class? Does it have a `result` property? If yes, change it as described. Then, do you have a class named `BFResult`? If yes, add the `<JsonProperty("event")>` attribute to the `Public Property bfevent As BFEvent`, rename `bfevent` to `EventData`. You're good to go.

Comment: Boom. Many Thanks. Would be good to understand exactly why that has worked if you can spare 5 mins, or point me to a suitable website. Very grateful either way

Comment: You can deserialize a collection of class objects to an array. Not forbidden. A `List(Of class)` is handled better (both on the deserializer side and your side, easier to use). -- When a property of the original JSON has a name that doesn't work well with the language in use (for example - as in your case - the property name equals a reserved word of the language) - or you don't like the original name for any reason - you can add a `<JsonProperty("...")>` attribute to the class property which references the original JSON property name. (...)

Comment: (...) You can then assign any name to your property: the deserializer will use the property name you specified. When serializing the class structure, it will instead use the original name, specified in the `<JsonProperty("...")>`, so the JSON output will match the original. Handy if you have to POST the JSON to a service that, of course, is expecting to receive a JSON with specific names.

Comment: I forgot a note: when you have a `DateTime` type property, it might be better to define it as a `DateTimeOffset`: `Public Property openDate As DateTime => Public Property openDate As DateTimeOffset`.